# How to pass an object to an action method in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can pass an object to be edited from my view to my Upsert action method , using Tag-Helpers like this ...

This is my Index.cshtml:( Take a look at Edit link bellow)

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.CategoryID    </td>
                <td>@item.CategoryName    </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Upsert" asp-route-CategoryID="@item.CategoryID" asp-route-CategoryName="@item.CategoryName">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

This is my action method:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Upsert(Category category)
    {
        ViewBag.Name = category.CategoryName;
        ViewBag.ID = category.CategoryID;
        return View();
    }
```

And the data will pass to the Upsert action method successfully.

Question: How to pass data in jquery/ajax? For that I need to have a link like this :

```
 <a href="/Admin/Category/Upsert/@item.CategoryID" >Edit</a>
```

and I really can't use Tag-Helpers in jquery.I can only pass CategoryID in jquery/ajax and do not know how to pass another field CategoryName and finally pass a Category object to my Upsert action method? 
In bellow, I get my data calling GetAll method ( so type: "GET" ) and render data in a table and create an Edit button for each row, I want to pass a complete object to Upsert method  ( so type: "POST") ? I can make a variable in my each loop but out of the loop it is undefined !

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/Admin/Category/GetAll",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        var html = '';
        $.each(result, function (key, item) {
            html += `
                     <tr>
                       <td>${item.categoryID}</td>
                       <td>${item.categoryName}</td>
                       <td> <div class="text-center">
                            <a href="/Admin/Category/Upsert/${item.categoryID}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                     </td>
                     </tr>
                   ` ;
            console.log(item);
        });
        console.log(result);
        $('#tblData tbody').html(html);
    },

});
```

Comment: You cannot post data to and HttpGet method. You need to change the method to HttoPost to be able to accept an object as parameter

Comment: I changed Upsert method to [HttpPost], and defined an object/variable of category and put it in data of ajax,  but category in method is still null and nothing sent to action method.

Comment: Can you update your code in the question along with jquery and Category object

Comment: Your ajax code is still showing  type: "GET",

Comment: I use type: "GET" for showing categories in a table and I have no problem there. GetAll method should be [HttpGet] and Upsert method should be [HttpPost]. After displaying the records in a table, it create an Edit button for each item/row. Now the problem arose: how to pass item (a category/an object) to my Upsert controller using Ajax ?? Is there a short way to pass data in a link/simple line? as we do with Tag-Helpers? If not what should I do?

Comment: To simplify, let's suppose I have a category object  in a table and need to know how to pass it to my Upsert controllers, all things I found on web, sending just an id and use the id to Find(id) from data base . But I want to send all the category rather than just CategoryID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points you should know:

1.The link is a Get request, so you should change `[HttpPost]` on **Upsert** method to `[HttpGet]`.

2.`asp-route-*` generates the query string not the route value in the url ,if you want to generate a link in success function of  ajax and click it to send a Category object **Upsert** method, change the code like below:

```
    $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                html += `
                         <tr>
                           <td>${item.categoryID}</td>
                           <td>${item.categoryName}</td>
                           <td> <div class="text-center">
                                <a href="/Admin/Category/Upsert?CategoryID=${item.categoryID}&CategoryName=${item.categoryName}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                </div>
                         </td>
                         </tr>
                       ` ;
                console.log(item);
            });
```

Result

[image]

Comment: WOW !! Nobody knew what I meant but you !! Thanks a lot :)